# downcasting standard layout struct to derived struct with the same data members

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, type-punning

I receive a pointer p to a struct S from C code and want to downcast it in C++ with

`static_cast<S_extended*>(p)`
where

1. S_extended is derived from S but just adds some methods to S so that the struct remains trivial and having standard layout (no virtual functions, no special functions, etc. are added).
2. No new data members are added into derived class.

Does such casting cause undefined behavior?

For example,

```
typedef struct S{
  uint32_t data;
} S;

struct S_extended
: public S {
  uint32_t getData(){return data;}
};

S s = {1};

uint8_t f(){
  return static_cast<S_extended*> (&s) -> getData();  // UB ???
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do this in the first place vs. just making functions that take `const S&` as an argument, etc.

Comment: the cast itself is not UB but accessing the function is.

Comment: @tadman upcasting is going from derived to base.  downcasting is going from base to derived.

Comment: @NathanOliver I guess I always got that terminology backwards, likely because it's never explicitly expressed as such in the code.

Comment: @tadman why... I want the struct S to satisfy some concept that expects member functions, not free functions

Comment: It's quite common to inherit from C `struct`s to add default initialization and member functions - and then provide pointers to instances of those extended `struct`s to C functions, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/z1664o1x8). Isn't that an option?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Unfortunately, no. The struct is created in C code and is passed to C++

Comment: You could have a struct that wraps around the other using a pointer and provides functions, but at some point you'll need to evaluate if all this is even worth it. The cost of adding non-virtual functions is really low, if not zero in many cases. Still, if you're stuck using C structures, you may as well use C-style code: Functions that take pointers or references. Not everything will be clean C++ code if there's external constraints like that.

Comment: @user396672 Ok, then on the topic of concepts: You may want to do like the standard library has done for arrays etc. You don't check if a container has a `.begin()` member function. You check if `std::begin(container)` is valid. The `std::begin` function will then use `.begin()` if it exists or fallback to providing a pointer to the first element for arrays etc. Provide stand-alone functions that calls the member functions if they exist - or use a C approach if they don't. The concept then becomes easy to write.

Comment: @tadman yes, I considered this solution, but I was wondering is it possible to do this with zero overhead, so I asked this question )

Comment: @TedLyngmo: I'll think about this possibility.. thank you for suggestion

Comment: @user396672 I'm thinking something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/YqzfMGzWT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are attempting to do is UB in multiple ways.
Let's start with the fact that down-casting to a derived class isn't possible as per [C++23 [expr.static.cast] p2](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#2) if you don't have an object of the derived type.

Even if it was possible to `static_cast` in this case, you would immediately run into another form of undefined behavior. Up until C++20, this would be:

> If a non-static member function of a class `X` is called for an object that is not of type `X`, or of a type derived from `X`, the behavior is undefined.

- [C++20 [class.mfct.non-static.general] p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.mfct.non-static.general#2)

`S` is not the same type as `S_extended` or derived from `S`, and you are calling a member function of `S_extended` for an object of type `S`. The behavior is undefined.

In C++23, this requirement was generalized for member access `E1.E2`:

> If `E2` is a non-static member and the result of `E1` is an object whose type is not [similar](https://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual#def:similar_types) to the type of `E1`, the behavior is undefined.

- [C++23 [expr.ref] p8](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#8)

Note that *similar* means `S` and `S_extended` would need to be pretty much the same type, and they are not.

---

*Note: This C++23 change was made in [CWG2535 Type punning in class member access](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2535.html)*

Answer (score 3):

> Does such casting cause undefined behavior?

Yes, the cast itself has undefined behavior. Whether or not you are adding data members and whether or not the classes are standard-layout or trivial is irrelevant. See [[expr.static.cast]/11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.static.cast#11.sentence-5).

Answer (score 2):

The fact that it's standard layout doesn't come into play at all. A `static_cast` is an absolute assertion by the programmer to the compiler that this value has the correct type. If the assertion is false, it's undefined behavior. Will it work? Probably, for a minute. But it's certainly not standard behavior.

I don't know what your background is, but I've seen a lot of Python and Java developers who start in C++ and try to fit everything into instance methods to get that nice, juicy `foo.bar()` syntax. And that's really just not how C++ is designed to work.

In C++, it's [recommended](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rc-member) to use free functions unless the function you're writing absolutely needs to access `private` members or should be `virtual`. In your case, since you're just adding helper functions, it's likely you can just write them as free-standing functions which take an `S*` (or, better, `S&` or `const S&`) as their first argument. You do have to call them as free functions (since Uniform Function Call Syntax has been proposed and declined many times by now), but you get nice loose coupling, [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl), and implicit conversions.

Comment: @user17732522 Seems I was confused. I see your answer and agree with you. Thanks for pointing it out! I'll leave the rest of my answer, as I think the suggestion of free functions is valuable, but good call.